# Do subclasses allocate memory and methods of their ancestors?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++, when a class inherits other class, if I create an object for the subclass, then will the subclass object create memory for all data members and member functions for the superclass, too?

Comment: You could probably do with re-phrasing this assertion as a question and you need a more meaningful title.

Comment: Voted to close so I could vote to reopen: this is a very basic question, but now that it's been edited, it's not a _bad_ question. It's certainly a real question.

Comment: Really, does nobody else think it should be reopened to give the OP a chance?

Answer (score 6):

Yep (though the member functions per se don't *need* memory... vtables are another issue, and are per-class and not per-instance anyway) -- an instance of the subclass "embeds", if you will, one of the superclass.  Say all instance variables are 32-bit ints for simplicity: if the superclass has 3 and the subclass adds 2 more, then each instance of the subclass will allocate 5 x 4 = 20 bytes -- 8 for its own instance variables, plus 12 for the instance variables of the superclass. (Plus 4 bytes for a vtable pointer iff there are any virtual methods in play).

So, what's the *question*...?